# MySQL query execution time is fast, but fetching rows is slow?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this query on phpmyadmin, it takes about 30 seconds to fetch the results, but once the results have successfully loaded, it says "Query took 0.5029 seconds".

**Why does it say 'Query took 0.50 seconds' if the results take 30 seconds to load?**

My Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `documents` WHERE disable=0 AND author=7 AND MATCH(text) AGAINST('"chocolate"')
```

The field I am searching (named "text") has a field type of "mediumtext", and each text row contains about 200kb of text. The total size of the table is 15,000 rows and 1.5GB of text.

Does anyone know what causes this to happen?

Comment: . . I don't understand your question.  You have described why this is happening.  Your rows are quite large.

Comment: My question is why does phpmyadmin say the query only took 0.50s when the page takes 30 seconds to show the results?

Comment: . . Because that is the time the *database* needs to find the results.  Returning them to the application is an entirely different matter.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH. That solved my problem! Instead of doing a SELECT ALL, I changed it to only select the fields that I need and it made the query return much faster!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to expand on my comment.

When a database reports on the time to complete a query, that is generally the time only within the database.  It might or might not include the time to compile the query.  It does not include the time to return the results.

Your data rows are quite wide, because of the text column on the data.  So, you have a situation where running the query in the database is quite fast.  But the resulting rows are very big -- so it takes lots of time to return them to the user.

Perhaps further complicating the timing is that you might be looking at when *all* the rows are returned rather than just for the first row to return (that is also a confusion with timings sometimes).

In any case, if you don't need the wide columns, just select the columns that you do need.  That has little effect on the query processing time, but it could have a big impact on the time to return the results.

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1 Select * from anytable is a BAD idea.
Just ask @supercoolville for clarification.

Comment: this is a generic suggestion which doesn't address the specific issue

Comment: @Guile  Supercool thinks it was the CORRECT resolution for his specific question.  There are millions more with the very SAME problem, they just do not realize the waste of using SELECT * in their queries.